# How can I access and set value to struct properties with his name as String

Tags: ios, swift, object, struct

I want to access to structure properties with its name as String . Let me explain

I can create and access to structure properties like below perfectly

**Example Struct**

```
struct MyStruct{
    var property1 : String?
    var property2 : String?
    ....
}

var obj = MyStruct()
obj.property1 = "value1"
```

my backend api sending to me the properties name from server . It something like :

```
 {
 "variable1" : "bla bla"
 "variable2" : "bla bla"
 ....
 }
```

I'm getting this values and do some operations and setting my structure.

> Sending model and fetching model are not same by the way.Its just an example

In my situation , I'm sending this structure to server api and imagine this structure has lots of properties. Everytime when I do some operations and sending to server on app I dont want to use to set model like that.

```
obj.variable1 = "gettingValueFromUser2"
obj.variable2 = "username"
obj.variable3 = "bla bla"
....
```

I have already have property names. How can I set this structure properties like

```
func setProp(propName : String , propVal : String){
    //propName is "variable1"
    obj.propName = propVal 
}
```

> I know I can do using class with KVP but I need to use with structure

Comment: How you are planning to add value to your struct properties ??

Comment: If this is ***your backend*** reconsider the design. It runs contrary to Swift strong types.

Comment: Like in function. not want to use init @argus7

Comment: So , there is only 1 way to set this. Its obj.variable1 = "bla bla". I can't use field name even backend server send it to me which gonne be set ? @vadian

Comment: Don't fight the system. It's pretty inefficient to map values to keys unless you send something like CSV where the first line represents the field names.

Comment: Can't you use dictionary instead then?

Comment: Service use GET method so I can't @thiscommunityistoxic

Comment: I don't see how GET and dictionary contradict each other. You want to achieve something like `obj.propName = propVal `? so with dictionary you get `dict[propName] = propVal`. And then you use `URLQueryItem` to serialize those params into URL query params (if this is what you mean by "service uses GET")